# undefined method where function in laravel

Tags: laravel, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been trying to filter out the product. If their category is popular, it will be retrieved. However, it's an error if I use a where in my controller. I think there's a wrong in my query?

Error: Call to undefined method Google\Cloud\Firestore\QuerySnapshot::where()

Language: PHP
Framework: Laravel 9
Database: Firebase, firestore

What i have tried so far:

- [Cloud Firestore QuerySnapshot Where function field not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72923045/cloud-firestore-querysnapshot-where-function-field-not-supported) [still returning the same error]
- [Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient::collection()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72485235/fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-method-google-cloud-storage-stora) [not applicable to mine]

controller:

```
$product = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('Products')->documents();
        $query1 = $product->where('category', isEqual: "popular");
        $popular = $query1->documents();
        return view('admin.product', compact('product', 'popular'));
```

Comment: remove ``->documents();`` from the ``$product`` as you're trying to use where method on the result and no on the query builder which is why ``where`` is not available. Also, then you need to introduce another variable to store the query builder so that you can also get the ``products``

Comment: @OMiShah that worked. thank u. Can u post it so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `->documents()` from the `$product` as you're trying to use the `where` method on the result and not on the query builder which is why `where` is not available. Also, then you need to introduce another variable to store the query builder so that you can also get the products.

**Updated code:**

```
$query = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection('Products');

$product = $query->documents();

$popular = $query->where('category', isEqual: "popular")->documents();

return view('admin.product', compact('product', 'popular'));
```