# Return compact Laravel always returns null

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using laravel framework for my website. I want to return value only from database without view but always get null.

Controller Code :

```
public function visitDetail($key) {
    $visitDetail = app('firebase.firestore')->database()->collection($this->tableVisit)->document($key)->snapshot();
    return compact('visitDetail');
}
```

Result :

[image: Result]

visitDetail variable value :

[image]

Comment: if you are not passing the variable to the view, then why don't just use `return $visitDetail`?

Comment: I try to return $visitDetail but got an error Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given.

Comment: use `return response()->json([ 'visitDetail' => $visitDetail ])` if you want to send a json response. laravel response types can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses)

Comment: Still same, when i try to hit the endpoint it return {"visitDetail":{}}

Comment: This means that `$visitDetail` cannot be converted to JSON. If it is an instance of a class you own then you should implement the [`JsonSerializable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface on it

Comment: Try removing `->snapshot()` from `$visitDetail` as per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74333416/20239914) OR may be use `$visitDetail->data()` to send as per [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

Comment: @AnthonyRafael Does my comment help. If so also check this [**snippet**](https://codefile.io/f/rzyBHziDBvjm559QgAYg) about changes required If this is helpful then I will post as an answer. so other community members will also get the answer for this question.

Comment: Hi does my comment helped if so acknowledge so I will post as a answer

Comment: The answer from you Rohit Kharche for removing ->snapshot() from $visitDetail is correct. But i take another alternative by looping the $visitDetail and push it to collection only for important data. Sorry if it's too long for answer your question